# FormMethod.Post in MVC4 has unexpected behavior

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following View:

```
    @model DocuLive.ViewModels.InstallationRequestViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "AttachDB";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminPage.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>AttachDB</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AttachDB","AppStart", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <p>Database DocuLive already exists on the server where you attempted installation. Do wish to attach existing DB to this installation of DocuLive? Details below will be used for this attempt.</p>

        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="command" value="Attach" />
                <input type="submit" name="command" value="Start over" />
            </p>
            <legend>DB server credentials</legend>

            <div class="display-label">
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Server)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Server)
            </div>

            <div class="display-label">
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="display-label">
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

I have follownt two methods in controller:

```
        public ActionResult AttachDB(InstallationRequestViewModel requestVM)
        {
            if (requestVM != null)
                return View("AttachDB", requestVM);
            else
            {
                TempData["Fail"] = "DocuLive database exist, but inicalization request has null value and cannot be used to attach DB";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        private async Task<ActionResult> AttachDB(InstallationRequestViewModel requestVM, string command)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (command)
                    {
                        case "Attach":
                            // do something complex and return RedirectToAction
                        case "Start over":
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        default:
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Fail"] = ex.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

For some reason when i submit the form with either button, it hits the first method with no regard to fact that I explicitly specified FormMethod.Post for the form to make sure that submitting the form will take user to the second method that actually contains some business logic.

It is very strange because I am using similar approach all over the app and so far I had no issues with this.

Can anyone advise, why submitting the form with either button is considered Get instead of POST?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I made the second method private by accident. Pretty stupid mistake...